# What is the correct way of using calloc for x86 ISA

Tags: c

I was shown many ways of using calloc and malloc: with casting, without, etc
So here I have two option how I can use calloc. I am curious which one is right for x86 isa.

If I have the following:

```
typedef struct node{
    int numOfOccur; 
    int numOfSuperWords;
    struct node *children;
}NodePtr;

NodePtr* temp = &root;
```

How would be correct to allocate memory using calloc.

1. Option 1

   ```
   temp -> children[currChar].children = (NodePtr *)calloc(27, sizeof(struct node));
   ```
2. Option 2

   ```
   temp -> children[currChar].children = calloc(27, sizeof(children[currChar].children));
   ```

Comment: The correct way to call `calloc` is independent of the ISA.

Comment: then why in old books we need all these casting.. but today people use it without casting and other stuff. Some things changed

Comment: The language might have changed.  That's nothing to do with the ISA.

Comment: [In C you should not cast `malloc` and related functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). In fact, in C you should not cast any functions returning `void *`. It has nothing to do with the CPU instruction set.

Comment: These "old" books are either bad (and therefore they are not edited anymore) or describe C++, which is another language.

Comment: Also your option 2 is wrong, because the expression for the `sizeof` operation is invalid, try it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several correct ways to write this. I would prefer the following:

```
temp->children[currChar].children = calloc(27, sizeof(struct node));
```

(i.e. use the type name instead of the long expression, and [no cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).)

Apart from that, I am not terribly keen on the magic number (`27`).